# i want c# programme to do this operation

Tags: c#-3.0

```
IF
7 - 3 = 124
6 + 3 = 279
5 - 2 = 63
11 + 2 = 2613

Then,
15 - 3 =?
```

Comment: You want people on SO to answer your interview question?!?

Comment: oh the joys of homework. never mind, it's almost the summer break..!!

Comment: Dlaor - neither does the the OP, hence the question :-)...

Comment: The right answer is "a horrid misuse of operator overloading".

Answer (score 7):

`15 - 3 = You're not getting the job by doing this.`

Comment: Best answer possible to this question.

Comment: Crap, I was just about to solve it...

Comment: 3612 is absolutely correct, Muhammad. :-)

Comment: @Kyle Rozendo - I know it is stupid but... I don't know why.